# How to do a sprite animation in blender like undertale with good alpha channel

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I tried to do a sprite animation but it messed up and the alpha channel doesn't work yes I used images as planes.[image: https://i.gyazo.com/57113552be74c6abb246b920980b0fda.gif]